# Scraping a website with Python, edit the HTML and then re-open the url with the edited html

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was wondering if there is a way to scrape a website using Python, then I can do some changes in the HTML or the scraped data (for example change the font color or background color..etc) and then open the edited HTML in the browser.

I was able to get the URL and edit the data using requests and BeautifulSoup, but then I got stuck on how to re-open the HTML file in the browser.

**This is my code:**

[image]

So now I got the whole html data in the variable lime_changed but am stuck on how to re-open it, can someone help me with this one.

Comment: you could try writing the new html string into a html file and open it in your browser

Comment: If you can give up on python, "Tamper Monkey" can do what your are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your goal is, you can also use Selenium to automate browser control from Python